# How to convert ajax code into vue.js axios method in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js

If user click on like button web page not refresh and count of the likes also updated without refreshing so, In first I have written in ajax then I want to convert it into vue.js after converting into vue.js its not working. Can any one please help me to achieve this.

Here I have written vue.js axios method. That I have accessed in html template
**html template**

```
<div id = "deals-vikreya">
    <a class="likebutton" style="
     {% if request.session.email %}pointer-events: auto;
     {% else %}pointer-events: none;{% endif %}" id="like-{{i.id}}" href="#"
     data-catid="{{ i.id }}">
     <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" id="like-icon-{{i.id}}" aria-hidden="true"
     style="color: gray"></i>
     </a>
     <span id="cm_count{{i.id}}">
     ({{ c_count }})
     </span>
</div>
```

**vue.js axios**

```
<script>
    new Vue({
     el: '#deals-vikreya',
        data() {
            return {};
        methods: {
            $('.likebutton').click(function(){
            var catid;
            catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
            console.log(catid);
            axios(
            {
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'post_comment_like' + catid %}", //django path name
                data:{
                         post_id: catid
                },
                success: function( data )
                {
                console.log("like saved");
                console.log(data.comment_count);
                document.getElementById("cm_count"+catid).innerHTML ="(" + data.comment_count + ")";
                $( '#like-'+ catid ).attr("href", "/post_comment_like_remove/" + catid);
                $( '#like-icon-'+ catid ).css("color", "#DB0038");
                }
             })
        });
        },

    })
</script>
```

Comment: i think you don't need the jquery in vuejs.

Comment: without Jquery how can we achieve that please help me